# C++ driver program not see header file

Tags: c++

ok, what am I missing now my driver file does not see the header file. here are the files. the first file will see the header, but project1_task2 will not see the header. this is for an assignment im late uugghh im using notepad++ on a centos system. what am i missing.  thank you. when i compile project1_task2.cpp it says:

project1_task2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
project1_task2.cpp:27:9: error: ‘class Complex’ has no member named ‘add’
c3 = c1.add(c2);
^
project1_task2.cpp:30:9: error: ‘class Complex’ has no member named ‘sub’
c3 = c1.sub(c2);
^
project1_task2.cpp:33:9: error: ‘class Complex’ has no member named ‘mult’
c3 = c1.mult(c2);
^
project1_task2.cpp:36:9: error: ‘class Complex’ has no member named ‘div’
c3 = c1.div(c2);

Header:

```
//newcomplex1.h

#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

class Complex
{
private:
double realPart;
double imaginaryPart;
public:
Complex(double real=0, double imag=0); //constructor that initializes the complex number by default arguments
double getReal(); //get function that returns the real part of the complex number
double getImag(); //get function that returns the imaginary part of the complex number
void setReal(double real); //set function that sets the real part of the complex number
void setImag(double imag); //set function that sets the imaginary part of the complex number
void print(); //function that displays the complex number
friend Complex add(const Complex&, const Complex&); //function that returns the sum of two complex numbers
friend Complex sub(const Complex&, const Complex&); //function that returns the difference of two complex numbers
friend Complex mult(const Complex&, const Complex&); //function that returns the product of two complex numbers
friend Complex div(const Complex&, const Complex&); // function that returns the quotient of two complex numbers
};
#endif
```

File 1:

```
//newcomplex1.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include"newcomplex1.h"

using namespace std;

Complex::Complex(double real, double imag)
{
realPart = real;
imaginaryPart = imag;
}

double Complex::getReal() {
return this->realPart;
}


double Complex::getImag() {
return this->imaginaryPart;
}

void Complex::setReal(double real) {
realPart = real;
}


void Complex::setImag(double imag) {
imaginaryPart = imag;
}

Complex add(const Complex& c1, const Complex& c2) {
Complex temp = Complex();
temp.realPart = c1.realPart + c2.realPart;
temp.imaginaryPart = c1.imaginaryPart + c2.imaginaryPart;
return temp;
}
Complex sub(const Complex& c1, const Complex& c2) {
Complex temp = Complex();
temp.realPart = c1.realPart - c2.realPart;
temp.imaginaryPart = c1.imaginaryPart - c2.imaginaryPart;
return temp;
}

Complex mult (const Complex& c1, const Complex& c2) {
Complex temp = Complex();
temp.realPart = (c1.realPart * c2.realPart) - (c1.imaginaryPart * c2.imaginaryPart);
temp.imaginaryPart = (c1.realPart * c2.imaginaryPart) + (c1.imaginaryPart * c2.realPart);
return temp;
}
Complex div (const Complex& c1, const Complex& c2) {

Complex temp = Complex();
temp.realPart = (c1.realPart*c2.realPart + c1.imaginaryPart*c2.imaginaryPart)/(c2.realPart*c2.realPart +c2.imaginaryPart*c2.imaginaryPart);
temp.imaginaryPart = (c1.imaginaryPart*c2.realPart - c1.realPart*c2.imaginaryPart)/(c2.realPart*c2.realPart +c2.imaginaryPart*c2.imaginaryPart);
return temp;
}

void Complex::print() {
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2);
if(realPart!=0)
cout << realPart;
if(imaginaryPart!=0)
{
if(imaginaryPart==1)
cout << "+i";
else if(imaginaryPart==-1)
cout << "-i";
else if(imaginaryPart>0 && realPart!=0)
cout <<"+"<< imaginaryPart<< "i";
else
cout << imaginaryPart<< "i";
}
cout<<endl;
}
```

Driver:

```
//project1_task2.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "newcomplex1.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double real, imag;

cout<<"Enter the first complex real_part imaginary_part : "<<endl;
cin>>real>>imag;
Complex c1(real, imag);
cout<<"Enter the second complex: real_part imaginary_part : "<<endl;
cin>>real>>imag;
Complex c2(real, imag);


cout<<"The two complex numbers entered are :"<<endl;
cout<<"c1 = "; c1.print();
cout<<"c2 = "; c2.print();

Complex c3;
cout<<"The arithmetic operations on these two numbers: "<<endl;
cout<<"c1 + c2 = ";
c3 = c1.add(c2);
c3.print();
cout<<"c1 - c2 = ";
c3 = c1.sub(c2);
c3.print();
cout<<"c1 * c2 = ";
c3 = c1.mult(c2);
c3.print();
cout<<"c1 / c2 = ";
c3 = c1.div(c2);
c3.print();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `friend` functions are not class members.

Comment: How much of this code is needed to replicate the problem? Is it really the most minimal [mcve] possible? And what is the actual build error you get? Please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build output. Also please try to illustrate the directory structure you have, where are the files located in relation to each other? And what flags and options are you using when building? How do you build?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
c3 = add(c1, c2);
```

Instead of

```
c3 = c1.add(c2);
```

Because `add` is not a member function:

```
friend Complex add(const Complex&, const Complex&);
```